# Filter Text File into HTML Table in PHP

Tags: php, html, file, text

Hi everyone i have **txt file** with the following contents:

```
    Name        : MyName1
    State       : Apt
    PathName    : C:\xx\MyName1.txt

    Name        : MyName2
    State       : Apf
    PathName    : C:\xx\MyName2.txt

    Name        : MyName3
    State       : Apf
    PathName    : C:\xx\MyName3.txt
```

Is there any way to convert this text file into **HTML TABLE** by using PHP code to look something like this:

```
        Name        State   PathName
        MyName1     Apt     C:\xx\MyName1.txt
        MyName2     Apf     C:\xx\MyName2.txt
        MyName3     Apf     C:\xx\MyName3.txt
```

Comment: PLease show us you have taken an effort in any way to try and solve this yourself, this forum is not for making people do your work ;)

Comment: `is there any way`. Yes, there is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a blend of `file_get_contents()`, `foreach()` & `preg_replace()` for that like the commented code below illustrates:

**CONTENTS OF TXT FILE:**

```
    Name        : MyName1
    State       : Apt
    PathName    : C:\xx\MyName1.txt

    Name        : MyName2
    State       : Apf
    PathName    : C:\xx\MyName2.txt

    Name        : MyName3
    State       : Apf
    PathName    : C:\xx\MyName3.txt
```

**TABLE CREATION ALGORITHM:**

```
    <?php

        $txtFile        = __DIR__ . "/test.txt"; //<== PATH TO THE TXT FILE
        $txtFileData    = file_get_contents($txtFile);

        // CONVERT $txtFileData TO ARRAY BY SPLITTING AT THE NEW-LINE BOUNDARY.
        $arrTxtData     = explode("\n", $txtFileData);
        $sections       = array();
        $index          = 0;

        // LOOP THROUGH THE ARRAY (FROM ABOVE) AND BUILD SECTION GROUPS
        // USING THE EMPTY LINE AS THE CUE-POINT FOR THE NEXT SECTION GROUP
        foreach($arrTxtData as $line){
            if(!empty(trim($line))){
                $sections[$index][] = trim($line);
            }else{
                $index++;
            }
        }

        // EXTRACT THE VALUES FOR THE TABLE HEADINGS...
        $extract    = $sections[0];
        $heading1   = preg_replace("#(\t|\s)*?(\:.*)$#", "", $extract[0]);
        $heading2   = preg_replace("#(\t|\s)*?(\:.*)$#", "", $extract[1]);
        $heading3   = preg_replace("#(\t|\s)*?(\:.*)$#", "", $extract[2]);

        // BUILD THE HEAD-SECTION OF YOUR TABLE...
        $output     = "<table class=''>" . PHP_EOL;
        $output    .= "<tr class=''>" . PHP_EOL;
        $output    .= "<th class=''>{$heading1}</th>" . PHP_EOL;
        $output    .= "<th class=''>{$heading2}</th>" . PHP_EOL;
        $output    .= "<th class=''>{$heading3}</th>" . PHP_EOL;
        $output    .= "</tr>" . PHP_EOL;
        $output    .= "<tbody>" . PHP_EOL;

        // LOOP THROUGH ALL THE SECTIONS AND BUILD YOUR ROWS + CELLS
        foreach($sections as $section){
            $output.= "<tr>" . PHP_EOL;
            foreach($section as $data){
                $strVal = preg_replace("#(^.*?\:\s*?)#", "", $data);
                $output.= "<td class=''>{$strVal}</td>" . PHP_EOL;
            }
            $output.= "</tr>" . PHP_EOL;
        }
        // CLOSE OFF THE <TBODY> AND <TABLE> TAGS
        $output    .= "</tbody>" . PHP_EOL;
        $output    .= "</table>" . PHP_EOL;

        // ECHO THE RESULTING OUTPUT [THE TABLE]
        echo $output;
```

**RESULT OF THE ECHO STATEMENT:**

```
        Name        State   PathName
        MyName1     Apt     C:\xx\MyName1.txt
        MyName2     Apf     C:\xx\MyName2.txt
        MyName3     Apf     C:\xx\MyName3.txt
```

Comment: voted up just because of the effort

Comment: Me too & because it gives OP their desired result whereas the other answers don't - not that SO is a free-code service, but good effort `:)`

Answer (score 0):

```
// Read the contents of the file
$file = file_get_contents("someFile.txt");

// convert the file contents to lines of text
$lines = explode("\r\n", $ file);
```

Now you can access ANY line of data in the $lines array.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how to start with this,
use php explode to divide the long string with all the information in single rows
like :

```
$array = explode (" : ", $string);
```

This would divide every line of string around the `:` sign,
this way you have an array like so :

```
$array = [
    "Name",
    "Mynam1",
    "State",
    "Apt",
    "..."
];
```

Then you could use a for loop to loop through each item and store it as a key and value pair, meaning, every time a rray item has an even keynumber : 0,2,4, etc... it will be the name of the key you want (NAME, STATE , ...) and you can pair it into the result array together with it's value which will be the next item (so `$x + 1` ).

```
for($x = 0, $x < count($array); $x++) {
    if ( $x % 2 == 0 ) {
        $result_array["$array[$x]_$x"] = $array[$x+1];
    }
}
```

Using this method you will get an array like so:

```
$result = [
    "Name_1" => "Mynam1",
    "State_1" => "Apt",
    "..."
];
```

Now from there on out you should try and work that to your needs so you can use it as needed :)

Good luck !